# focal loss for imbalanced data using pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, bert-language-model, cross-entropy

I want to use focal loss with multiclass imbalanced data using pytorch . I searched got and try to use this code but I got  error

```
class_weights=tf.constant([0.21, 0.45, 0.4, 0.46, 0.48, 0.49])

loss_fn=nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights,reduction='mean')
```

and use this in train function

```
    preds = model(sent_id, mask, labels)
   
     # compu25te the validation loss between actual and predicted values
    alpha=0.25
    gamma=2
    ce_loss = loss_fn(preds, labels)
    pt = torch.exp(-ce_loss)
    focal_loss = (alpha * (1-pt)**gamma * ce_loss).mean()
```

the error is

```
TypeError: cannot assign 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object to buffer 'weight' (torch Tensor or None required)
```

in this line

```
loss_fn=nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights,reduction='mean')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing tensorflow and pytorch objects.

Try:

```
class_weights=torch.tensor([0.21, ...], requires_grad=False)
```

Comment: thank you very much